# How to keep a spring application up and running?

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application with a queue processing logic. I want to keep the service class active and running without a while loop . What are the best ways to do this in spring boot ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have anexecution thread every X time, you can implement TaskExecutor of Spring and add it a scheduler job to be execute so often as you want

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
  public void doSomething() {
     // process your queue
   }
```